# save to disk in append mode

Tags: rebol, rebol3, red

`save` is used to store data in a format more directly usable by REBOL, as stated [here](http://learnrebol.com/rebol3_book.html#section-13)
`write` has an append mode but it saves data in a raw mode.

My application needs to save a block of data (as a `map!`) to disk. Each couple of seconds it will generate a new element, up to tens of thousand of elements.

So, my question. I can `save` the whole data each couple of seconds.  But I'd like to know if I can append the new elements to disk using the `save` command or `save` format.  I guess that I could mimic the `save` format using the `write` command in `/append` mode. Is this the best solution, or is there another one I don't know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save` is a mezzanine function, that is basically `write mold`. So it's possible to mimic the `save` function using `write` or it's possible to update `save` function to support `/append` refinement.